# Changing the file position indicator of stdout

Tags: c, stdout

I am trying to mess with the file position indicator and write over stuff that is already on screen.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main ()
    {
       fpos_t position;


       fgetpos (stdout, &position);
       fputs ("That is a sample",stdout);
       fsetpos (stdout, &position);
       fputs ("This",stdout);

       return 0;
    }
```

I want this "This is a sample".  I got similar code right off of [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fsetpos/) the only difference is that they use an actual file and not stdout.  Is there some special exception for stdout of which I am unaware.

I thought I could treat stdout like a file.  For some reason I am getting this as output: `That is a sampleThisPress any key to continue . . .`  I would really like to know why.  [This guy](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/73984/) even asked the same question on with no response on cplusplus.com

I know about fseek and lseek and I might use those instead if they work but regardless I want to know why the above does not work.  If you have a better way of doing this I am open to suggestions but I still want to know what I am doing wrong here.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stdout doesn't have a concept of file positions when pointing at tty style devices, think of the old days of tty modems etc and once a character is sent it's sent. You may be able to send a sequence of characters to reposition the cursor after the event and overwrite text on the screen, but how you do that is dependent on the output device.

Comment: Would really only work for a particular kind of output device / terminal. I used to write code that did similar things for say a VT100 terminal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) which later became an ANSI standard. So it still might be a cool project, just will be heavily dependant on the system.

Comment: @ReallyBadAtStuff:  Don't bother rewriting the screen in text mode.  Instead, see [curses](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses) (now called ncurses), for a terminal type independent way to do it.

Comment: As wallyk said curses is the standard way to do it on Linux, if you're using that.

Comment: Haha I just had to do a project with ncurses and my teacher never even taught it he said he was "waving his hands at it."  So it was a bad experience lol. I got it working but ncurses is still a bit mysterious to me.  But I will look into it.  Edit@ PeterJ: Just saw the above comment does ncurses only work with linux?  The project I did was with linux but this one I am currently trying is one a windows machine.

Answer (score 4):

If what you are trying to achieve is to modify the output to a screen, you may want to look at ncurses (or something similar).

Or perhaps, if you just want something like this (a progress bar that shows how much "part2 is of the "total" work that is done so far):

```
....
cout << part * 100 / total << "% done\r"; cout.flush();
....
```

The \r is "carriage return", and will move the cursor back to the start of the line, without moving down.

Answer (score 2):

Your program will work if `stdout` is redirected to a file.  Terminals are not seekable, but disk files, and some other types of streams, are seekable.

There is a system call library call, [`isatty(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty), which is widely supported.  If it returns true, `stdout` is connected to a terminal-like device, and is not seekable.  If false, you can usually depend on it working.  I thought there was a `isapipe()` call, but I have never used it (only thought I remembered seeing it in the man pages), but I don't find it anywhere now.  Pipes tend not to be seekable as well (in most cases).